# Django unable to iterate prefetch_related objects at template

Tags: python, django, model, prefetch

I'm unable to access my prefetch_related objects at my template, can smb help

views.py

```
def support(request, pk=None):
    ...
    else:
        list_support_tickets = sorted(
            chain(
                SupportTickets.objects.filter(Q(status=0) | Q(status=1), requester=request.user).prefetch_related('reply_relation'), #Can't iter object
            ), key=attrgetter('creation_date'), reverse=True
        )
        paginator = Paginator(list_support_tickets, 10)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        support_tickets = paginator.get_page(page)
        args = {'support_tickets': support_tickets,
                'form': form
                }
        print(list_support_tickets)
        return render(request, template, args)
```

At my template I do the following:

```
    {% for support_ticket in support_tickets %}
    ...
        {% for reply in support_ticket.reply_relation %}
            <span class="font-size-small">We have a query, yeah</span>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

But I'm unable get a query here, error:

> TypeError: 'GenericRelatedObjectManager' object is not iterable

models.py

```
class SupportTicketMessages(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=referential_models, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='support_ticket_reply_author', verbose_name='Author', blank=True)
    reply = models.TextField(verbose_name="Reply Content", max_length=2000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)


class SupportTickets(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticket_id = models.IntegerField(default=ticket_id_generator, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, editable=False)
    requester = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    category = models.IntegerField(choices=TICKET_CATEGORY, verbose_name='Ticket Category')
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    problem_description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_OF_TICKET, verbose_name='Ticket Status', default=0)
    reply_relation = GenericRelation(SupportTicketMessages, related_query_name='reply_relation')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`support_ticket.reply_relation` is a *manager*, not a `QuerySet`, so you can not iterate over it, you use [**`.all()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#all) to iterate over this:

```
{% for support_ticket in support_tickets %}
…
    {% for reply_relation in support_ticket.reply_relation.all %}
        …
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```